# Adobe AIR call SoftKeyboardType Phone IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air, ane

is it possible to call phone (not number but phone) keyboard from adobe air on ipa IOS? or is there any ANE?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses the numeric keyboard and restricts the input to numbers:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.text.ReturnKeyLabel;
    import flash.text.SoftKeyboardType;
    import flash.text.StageText;

    public class StageTextNumber extends Sprite
    {
        public function StageTextNumber()
        {

            var text:StageText = new StageText();
            text.softKeyboardType = SoftKeyboardType.NUMBER;
            text.restrict = "0-9";
            text.returnKeyLabel = ReturnKeyLabel.GO;

            text.stage = this.stage;
            text.viewPort = new Rectangle(10, 10, 300, 40 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I know SoftKeyboardType.NUMBER, but with this I can't type #+* symbols

Comment: @VakhtangiBeridze I know, but that is the only possibility in AIR.